# WorkManager/PeriodicWorkRequest - When the next work will be executed if a previous work has been retried?

Tags: android, worker, android-workmanager

Let's say I enqueue a **periodic work** with a **repetition of 1 day** and an **exponential backoff criteria**. Let's also suppose I set an **initial delay** just to try to execute it for the **first time around 13:00**.

If the first work is executed at 13:05, fails, and then after several tries it eventually succeeds at 14:15, then when the next job will be executed?

A - Next day around 13:00

B - Next day around 14:15

In case of B, is there any way of having a more or less exact time schedule (I'm aware of the min flex duration) everyday regardless failures in some jobs rather than rescheduling it every time it executes?